# App crash with voice over whenever a textview with a link in it is activated

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

Stack trace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1ee50f, 0x00000001096f5d05 libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.DateComponents._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSDateComponents>) -> Foundation.DateComponents with unmangled suffix "_merged" + 85, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
frame #0: 0x00000001096f5d05 libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.DateComponents._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSDateComponents>) -> Foundation.DateComponents with unmangled suffix "_merged" + 85
frame #1: 0x000000010558e36f Invest`@objc InvestDashboard.textView(UITextView, shouldInteractWith : URL, in : _NSRange) -> Bool + 79 at InvestDashboard.swift:0
frame #2: 0x000000011fd478fc UIKit`-[UITextViewAccessibility accessibilityActivate] + 838
frame #3: 0x000000011fed29d2 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(UIStorage) accessibilityPerformAction:withValue:fencePort:] + 1448
frame #4: 0x000000011feaa63d UIAccessibility`_performActionCallback + 163
frame #5: 0x000000011fc0cec4 AXRuntime`_AXXMIGPerformAction + 107
frame #6: 0x000000011fc06f06 AXRuntime`_XPerformAction + 216
frame #7: 0x000000011fc16541 AXRuntime`mshMIGPerform + 266
frame #8: 0x0000000106d1ff89 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
frame #9: 0x0000000106d1ff01 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 465
frame #10: 0x0000000106d18045 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2389
frame #11: 0x0000000106d17494 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
frame #12: 0x000000010cc38a6f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
frame #13: 0x00000001078c2964 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
frame #14: 0x000000010467e99f InvestDemo`main + 111 at AppDelegate.swift:29
frame #15: 0x000000010b88268d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
frame #16: 0x000000010b88268d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

This happens whenever I use activate on a TextView that has a link in it. I've tried a lot of different things, like overriding `accessibilityActivate() -> Bool` but the app crashes before this method ever gets called. Any suggestions?

Comment: The crash is happening in the `shouldInteractWith` method in your `InvestDashboard` class. Post that method into your question.

Comment: I've put a break point on the first line of that method but the app crashes before that breakpoint is reached.

Comment: Does your method use `DateComponents`? You really should post the method if you want help.

Comment: The reason I have no code from any methods is that I haven't been able to even find the method that causes the crash and I suspect it's a UIKit bug. Like I said, the app crashes before `shouldInteractwith` gets called and `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ` happens in the App Delegate. And no, I'm not using `DateComponents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue and wanted to share so that others with the same confusing problem can fix it.

The first thing to do is to subclass `UITextView` and in that subclass override `func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool`. Then make a delegate that handles what happens when the TextView is activated and call it through the overridden method.

Then set the delegate of the TextView based on `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()`, so if voice over is running then set the `UITextViewDelegate` to `nil` which prevents the crash from happening and then the activation action is handled by the method you overrode in the subclass above. Finally, set up a listener for `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged` and set the `UITextViewDelegate` to `nil` when going from off to on, and setting it to the original delegation class for the opposite scenario.

Some code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class Test : UITabBarController, UITextViewDelegate, ActivationDelegate {

    var voiceOverRunning : Bool {
        get {
            return UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
        }
    }

    var testView = AccessibilityView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if !voiceOverRunning {
            testView.delegate = self
        } else {
            testView.activationDelegate = self
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.didChangeVoiceOver),
            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged),
            object: nil)
    }

    func doStuff() {
        /*
         Do what you want to happen here on activation
         */
    }


    @objc
    func didChangeVoiceOver(){
        testView.delegate              = voiceOverRunning ? nil : self
        testView.activationDelegate    = voiceOverRunning ? self : nil
    }


}

protocol ActivationDelegate : class {
    func doStuff()
}
class AccessibilityView : UITextView {

    var activationDelegate : ActivationDelegate!

    override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {
        activationDelegate.doStuff()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, see the edit to the post. There might be some small errors since I switched jobs and don't have access to the same code base anymore nor do I develop swift/iOS anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem, except my unconditional bridging error was with NSURL. It occurs when I have static text set as a UIAccessibilityTrait along with the UITextView having a link in attributed text. The only possible answer I found was that it is a bug in the signature of the bridging header, and one of the languages is trying to call the delegate methods differently than it should. My solution was removing the (shouldInteractWith url) delegate method, but it also seemed to work if I duplicated the method and made some of the parameters optional. I didn't really see the delegate methods being called though, so I think browser-opening the link is handled automagically.

TLDR; I think you have three options:

1. You can disable static text if you don't need it.
2. Add duplicate delegate methods with optional parameters until you find the signature that works.
3. Remove the delegate methods completely.

Comment: I encountered this crash as well, very puzzling. Turns out removing static text was the simplest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and noticed this detail:  The crash only happens for me when I have the legacy iOS 9 version of the `UITextViewDelegate` implementation.  My code looked like this:

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Removing `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:)` and the `@available` (and raising my target to iOS 10) resolved the crash.

Unfortunately this isn't an option for me.

I logged https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=34187849 for the issue.  I'm sure it'll just get ignored since it involves iOS 9 support.

Comment: I've talked with Apple engineer today, the bug was filed to UIKit so no in accessibility was handling it. they just routed it to the right group. I hope it will be fixed soon.